# ZODB Mountpoint broken?

Tags: plone, zope

ZODB Mountpoint distributed with Plone 4.1.2 always seems to create OFS.Folder even if the container-class is specified.

Also getting a `"KeyError: item already present wih same id"` due to `_setObject` and `_setOb` both being called.

Am trying to mount a plone.app.folder.folder.ATFolder from a separate Data.fs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by removing some code to do with a "Faux" object in MountedObject.py

Seems this is not needed anymore and is getting in the way of things.